# Export CATIA - Maya to Unity Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, maya, cad, catia

Good morning,

I've been trying to export a CATIA project file (.CATProduct) to Unity. To do so, I  was trying to use Maya in order to create a .fbx file and then import it to Unity as an asset. However, I don't know why I can't see anything in the Scene when I put it into the Hierarchy Panel.

First, I import the CATIA File to Maya. It seems working perfectly since I can see in Maya the CAD with its PartBody and Mutisections. However, whenever I try to export it (via the "Game Exporter" or the "Export All/Selections"), I found a warning/error message, which is: "This scene contains at least one transform node with multiple shape nodes. The plug-in will export only one of the shape nodes", which is, actually, only the PartBody.

Any idea how to solve this issue? it happens to me with every CATIA file...

Thanks in advance!